# Checking when a form is submitted and getting values

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I have a WebBrowser with this page in it:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="input1" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" />
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I was wondering how it would be possible through MSHTML to get the input values *when the form is submitted*.

Comment: If you want a web site, why don't you host it on a web server? What's the point of a desktop application that acts like a web site?

Comment: Because I need it to use jQuery animations, which I understand are very hard to duplicate in Windows Forms.

Comment: Yes, impossible. Windows Forms doesn't use jQuery, it uses an entirely different programming interface. jQuery is a web thing.

Comment: So do you know how I can do this?